# VSTS NodeJS API queue build

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to queue a build via the [NodeJS VSTS API (azure-devops-node-api)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-node-api)

So i use the `getDefinition` to get my build definition, then `queueBuild` with the returned result:

```
connection.getBuildApi().then((vstsBuild) => {
    vstsBuild.getDefinition(buildPublishToNexus, project).then((buildDefinition) => {
        vstsBuild.queueBuild(buildDefinition, project).then((defs) => {
            console.info('build', defs);
        }).catch(err => console.error('catch 1', err));
    }).catch(err => console.error('catch 2', err));
});
```

I get my build with all its reference but it keeps telling my this error:

```
{ '$id': '1',
     innerException: null,
     message: 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: build.Definition',
     typeName: 'System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib',
     typeKey: 'ArgumentNullException',
     errorCode: 0,
     eventId: 0 } }
```

Does someone have any information on how to get the `build.Definition`? The documentation is really poor.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution in the issues of the [vsts github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/147) :

> I would recommend queuing a build in the UI and watching the wire with chrome, fiddler, charles. Compare. Our web UI uses all public rest apis so it's implemented :) . More accurate than docs ...

So the payload would looks like:

```
        const vstsdef = {
        'queue': {'id': 1},
        'definition': {'id': 1},
        'project': {'id': '5fe64329-b654-4a20-a73c-375636ef1879'},
        'sourceBranch': 'refs/heads/mybranch',
        'sourceVersion': '',
        'reason': 1,
        'demands': ['option demands'],
        'parameters': '{"key":"value"}'
    };
```